# How to unwire event from control generically?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I need to unwire some events, temporarily, from my NumericUpDown controls because I am changing them programatically and don't want to trigger the ValueChanged event.  The code should look something like this:

```
private void UnwireNUD (NumericUpDown nud) {
   nud.ValueChanged -= numericUpDown_ValueChanged;
}
```

The numericUpDown_ValueChanged part is the part I don't know how to reference.  Has anyone done this before and wouldn't mind offering some assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the event delegate is hidden information. If you say "my NumericUpDown" do you control its source code? If not, you can only do it via Reflection, which you should not. The only other options is to change the subscribers in one way or another, like using a flag and ignoring the method call, or work with a wrapper object that has some sort of suppression logic.

Generally, it seems dangerous to assume all subscribers to not be interested in the event.

Comment: All the subscribers, in this particular instance, actually are NumericUpDown controls.  I was hoping to reference them with generic calls, but I went ahead and hardcoded their names for simplicity.  Thanks.